# ObjectInputStream.readObject appears to be stuck in multi-threaded server

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I am trying to send a pedestrian object to the server and the server to return a list of car drivers in a message object. But when I try to send the server seems to be stuck on the readObject function and the client is failing to initialize the Object output and Input streams. 
Here is my server code:

```
package eece350;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class SkillsServer {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private void acceptConnections() {
    try {
            int port = 7171;
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } 
    catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("ServerSocket instantiation failure");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
    }
// Entering the infinite loop
    while (true) {
                        try {
                            // wait for a TCP handshake initialization (arrival of a "SYN"
                            // packet)
                Socket newConnection = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("accepted connection");
                // Now, pass the connection socket created above to a thread and
                // run it in it
                // First create the thread and pass the connection socket to it
                // This is a non-blocking function: constructor of the class
                // ServerThread
                ServerThread st = new ServerThread(newConnection);
                // Then, start the thread, and go back to waiting for another
                // TCP connection
                // This also is not blocking
                new Thread(st).start();
            } 
                        catch (IOException ioe)
                        {
                            System.err.println("server accept failed");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, SQLException 
    {
        SkillsServer server = null;
        server= new SkillsServer();
        // call this function, which will start it all...
        server.acceptConnections();
    }
    // Internal class
    class ServerThread implements Runnable
    {
        private Socket socket;
                private ObjectOutputStream dataout;
        private ObjectInputStream datain;
                //private DataOutputStream outToClient;
        ServerThread(Socket socket) 
                {
            // Inside the constructor: store the passed object in the data
            // member
            this.socket = socket;
        }
  private List<CarDriver> getAllCarDriversWithCapacity() throws SQLException
  {
      String userName = "Mahdi";
        String password = "admin";
        String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"+";databaseName=Project350;Integrated Security=True";
        try 
        {   
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to database");
        }
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
        // TODO code application logic here
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query= "select * from CarDriver";
        ResultSet rs =stmt.executeQuery(query);
        CarDriver Car = new CarDriver();
        List<CarDriver> ListofDrivers = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            if(rs.getInt(12)>0)
            {
                Car.setDid(rs.getInt(0));
                Car.setName(rs.getString(1));
                Coordinates C = new Coordinates(rs.getDouble(2),rs.getDouble(3));
                Car.setLocation(C);
                C.setCoordinates(rs.getDouble(4),rs.getDouble(5));
                Car.setDestination(C);
                Car.setNumofPassengers(rs.getInt(6));
                Car.setChargingPerKilometer(rs.getDouble(7));
                Regulations r = new Regulations(rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11));
                Car.setRegulations(r);
                Car.setCarCapacity(rs.getInt(12));
                ListofDrivers.add(Car);
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
        return ListofDrivers;
  }
  private void InsertCarDriver(CarDriver cardriver) throws SQLException
    {
        String name=cardriver.getName();
        Coordinates Location=cardriver.getLocation();
        int did=cardriver.getDid();
        Coordinates Destination=cardriver.getDestination();
        int numberofPassengers=cardriver.getNumofPassengers();
        int CarCapacity=cardriver.getCarCapacity();
        Double charging=cardriver.getChargingPerKilometer();
        Regulations regulations=cardriver.getRegulations();
        String pets = regulations.pets;
        String kids = regulations.kids;
        String quietride = regulations.quietRide;
        String smoking = regulations.smoking;
        Double XLoc = Location.coordinateX;
        Double YLoc = Location.coordinateY;
        Double XDes = Destination.coordinateX;
        Double YDes = Destination.coordinateY;
        String userName = "Mahdi";
        String password = "admin";
        String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"+";databaseName=Project350;Integrated Security=True";
        try 
        {   
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot connect to database");
        }
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
        // TODO code application logic here
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "Insert into CarDriver values("+did+",'"+name+"',"+XLoc+","+YLoc+","+XDes+","+YDes+","+numberofPassengers+","+charging+",'"+smoking+"','"+pets+"','"+kids+"','"+quietride+"',"+CarCapacity+")";
        stmt.execute(query);
        conn.close();
    }
        public void run() 
        {
        try 
        {
    // Input and output streams, obtained from the member socket
    // object
             //outToClient = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))
             dataout = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
             datain = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Can't Initialize Streams");
        }
            String name="";
            Coordinates location;
            Coordinates Destination;
            int numberofPassenger;
            double chargingPerKilometer;
            int carCapacity,did;
            Regulations regulations;
            boolean connectionActive = true;
            String reply="";
            while (connectionActive) 
            {

                try 
                {
                    Object object;
                    object = datain.readObject();
                    if(object instanceof CarDriver)
                    {
                        /*String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"+";databaseName=EECE350Project;Integrated Security=True";
                        String userName = "Mahdi";
                        String password = "admin";
                        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();*/
                        CarDriver CarDriver1 = (CarDriver)object;
                        name=CarDriver1.getName();
                        location=CarDriver1.getLocation();
                        Destination=CarDriver1.getDestination();
                        numberofPassenger=CarDriver1.getNumofPassengers();
                        chargingPerKilometer=CarDriver1.getChargingPerKilometer();
                        carCapacity = CarDriver1.getCarCapacity();
                        regulations = CarDriver1.getRegulations();
                        did=CarDriver1.getDid();
                        reply = "I recieved your connection "+name;
                        this.InsertCarDriver(CarDriver1);
                        //outToClient.write(reply.getBytes(),0,reply.length());
                        //outToClient.write("\n".getBytes(),0,1);
                        //outToClient.flush();
                            try
                            {
                                System.out.println("Closing Socket");
                                datain.close();
                                //outToClient.close();
                                dataout.close();
                                socket.close();
                            }
                            catch(IOException ioe)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Unable to Close Socket");          
                            }
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Hello");
                        Regulations Pedregulations;
                        int pid=0;
                        Coordinates Pedlocation;
                        Coordinates PedDestination;
                        Pedestrian Pedestrian1 = (Pedestrian)object;
                        pid = Pedestrian1.pid;
                        Pedlocation = Pedestrian1.currentLocation;
                        PedDestination = Pedestrian1.Destination;
                        List <CarDriver> ListofCars = this.getAllCarDriversWithCapacity();
                        String mes = "";
                        Message message = new Message();
                        message.setMessage(ListofCars, mes);
                        reply= "I recieved your connection"+pid;
                        System.out.println(pid);
                        dataout.writeObject(message);
                        dataout.flush();
                    //outToClient.write(reply.getBytes(),0,reply.length());
                        //outToClient.write("\n".getBytes(),0,1);
                        //outToClient.flush();
                        //outToClient.writeBytes(reply);
                            try
                            {
                                System.out.println("Closing Socket");
                                datain.close();
                                //outToClient.close();
                                dataout.close();
                                socket.close();
                            }
                            catch(IOException ioe)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Unable to Close Socket");          
                            }
                        }
                }            
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                   System.out.println("No Object Recieved"); 
                } 
                catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("Class");
                } 
                catch (SQLException ex) 
                { 
                Logger.getLogger(SkillsServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } 
                //catch (SQLException ex) 
                //{
                    //return;
                //} 
            }
                try 
                {
        System.out.println("closing socket");
        datain.close();
        dataout.close();
        socket.close();
                } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                        {
                            System.out.print('.');
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

here is my client code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package eece350;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
// double hey = Double.parseDouble(string);
public class Pedestrian implements Serializable 
{
    public int pid=0;
    public Coordinates currentLocation;
    public Coordinates Destination;
    public Regulations preferences;
    public Pedestrian()
    {
        this.pid=0;
        this.Destination=null;
        this.currentLocation=null;
        this.preferences=null;
    }
    public Pedestrian(Coordinates currentLocation,Coordinates Destination,int pid,Regulations preferences) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        this.pid=pid;
        this.Destination=Destination;
        this.currentLocation=currentLocation;
        this.preferences=preferences;
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 7171); 
        ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()); 
        //BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        //String modifiedSentence="";
        System.out.println("heyo");
        outToServer.writeObject(this);
        Object object;
        object = inFromServer.readObject();
        if(object instanceof Message)
        {
            Message m = (Message)object;
            if(m.CarDrivers!=null)
            {
                for(int i =0;i<m.CarDrivers.size();i++)
                {
                    System.out.print(m.CarDrivers.get(i).getName());
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("Not a message");
        }
        //modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        //System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        outToServer.close();
        inFromServer.close();
        outToServer.flush();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {

    }
}
```

Please anyone could help me?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and moreover take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: No error just nothing happens

Comment: Have you debugged it?  Have your added println statements to see where it is stuck?  I doubt this has anything to do with multi-threads.  I suspect that the client is not flushing or something.  Best of luck.

Comment: @MahdiJaber And why you thinks that _client_ is making request to _server_ when there is no statement in `main` method?